# Getting error "cat: write error: Broken pipe" only when running bash script non-interactively

Tags: linux, bash, broken-pipe

I wrote a bash script where I define a variable like this:

```
var=$(cat $file_path | head -n $var2 | tail -n 1 | cut -f1)
```

Where `$file_path` simply contains the path to a file and `$var2` is an int, e.g., 1 or 2. The variable is therefore assigned the value of the first field of line number var2 of the file.

It works perfectly fine when I run this from the command line. However, when running the script containing this command, I get the error

> cat: write error: Broken pipe

Any idea why that is?

Comment: It's not the first field of the first line, it's the first field of the line number `var2`, right? Did you try running with `set -x` to see what your command expands to? Where do you set your variables?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, it takes the first filed on line number var2. I define var2 earlier in the script.

Comment: What about replacing the long pipe with a single command?  Perhaps something along the lines of this? `var=$(sed -ne "${var2}s/ .*//p;q" "$file_path")` (Notwithstanding whitespace issues of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use `cat`, since `head` takes a filename argument.

```
var=$(head -n $var2 $file_path | tail -n 1 | cut -f1)
```

Actually, there's no need to use any of those commands.

```
var=$(awk -v line=$var2 'NR == line { print $1; exit }' $file_path)
```